# AVX; byte multiplication; sum;

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, sse, simd, avx

I'm optimising the following code with AVX and want to know your opinion about the best approach.

There are two blocks of data 
`uint8 x[3][3];`
`uint8 y[3][3];`
result is `uint8` value which is sum of multiplication of corresponding elements like

```
res = (x[0][0]*y[0][0] + x[0][1]*y[0][1] + ... + x[3][3]*y[3][3]) >> NN
```

my concerns are:

- the result of `x[0][0]*y[0][0]` is `uint16`, so before any multiplications I need to unpack `uint8` into `uint16` which is extra instructions.
- the sum is `uint32`value, so before the merging multiplication results I need to unpack `uint16` into `uint32`. It's also overhead.

Is the any simpler/faster way to do the same math without extra unpack instructions?

Is there a way to multiply bytes and get `uint32` or `uint16` result w/o extra data conversions?

Thanks.

PS: x[3][3] and y[3][3] are both in a range [0...255]

Comment: The first step could be done by `(v)PUNPCKLBW`, the second by `(V)PMADDWD` + horizontal add. If you didn't have the requirement of `uint16_t`-intermediaries, you might ba able to instead use `(V)PMADDUBSW` for the first step, but the second step would be more complicated.

Comment: PMADDUBSW is multiplication of signed & unsigned bytes, not unsigned & unsigned. Unpacking (PUNPCKLBW) is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: If you know that one of your sources of bytes are signed positive, or unsigned and less than 0x7F, then you can use `pmaddubsw`.  Otherwise not.  I forget if AVX-512 has something.  Welcome to the joys of SSE/AVX's highly non-orthogonal choice of instructions.  I often happens that the perfect operation is available, but not for the element size or signedness you need.  You're probably going to need a `punpck` or `pmovzx`.